# How to access original numberValueFormatter in dygraph?

Tags: dygraphs

I have a simple dygraph with a valueFormatter like this

```js
axes: {
    y: {
        valueFormatter: function(val, opts, seriesName, dygraph, row, col) {
            if (seriesName === "Pass") {
                return val > 0 ? "Pass" : "Fail";
            } else {
                var x = this.attrs_.axes.y.valueFormatter(val, opts);
                return x;
            }
        },
    }
},
```

I want to call the original `utils.numberValueFormatter` from `dygraph-utils` for everything *except* the "Pass" series, but the above is the only way I could access it.

Is there a better/official way to call the default formatters?

EDIT:
After some tinkering I managed to get rid of the long reference chain and store the undamaged original numberValueFormatter in the graph.

Some more code for context.

```js
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    TheDataForDygraph,
    {
        series: {
            Pass: {
                drawPointCallback: Dygraph.Circles.HEXAGON,
                pointSize: 5,
                drawHighlightPointCallback: Dygraph.Circles.STAR,
                highlightCircleSize: 3,
            },
        },
        axes: {
            y: {
                valueFormatter: function(val, opts, seriesName, dygraph, row, col) {
                    if (seriesName === "Pass") {
                        return val > 0 ? "Pass" : "Fail";
                    } else {
                        var x = this.numberValueFormatter(val, opts);
                        return x;
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        labels: TheLabelsForDygraph,
        ylabel: 'Measurements',
    }
);

//Dirty hack, I don't know how else to get the original formatter.
g.numberValueFormatter = g.attrs_.axes.y.valueFormatter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `getOptionForAxis`:

```js
const valueFormatter = g.getOptionForAxis('valueFormatter', 'y');
```

To make sure it's the original, you could use a fresh object:

```js
const valueFormatter = new Dygraph(
  document.createElement('div'), [[0]]
).getOptionForAxis('valueFormatter', 'y');
```

Alternatively, if you're in an ES module context, you could try importing the symbol directly:

```
import {numberValueFormatter} from 'dygraphs/src/dygraph-utils';
```

Comment: Wow! Still active :-) Dygraphs is still going strong. Maybe we should have a 10 year birthday party one day. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do I assume correctly, that `g` would be our dygraph instance? When I try the code it gives me the already overwritten (new) valueFormatter that I put in the options. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I saw that a lot of internal functions are exported, like axis formatter and other helpers from util, but numberValueFormatter is not and there are some comments about it in the code ;-)

Comment: Yes, `g` would be a dygraph instance. If it returns your override, though, you'd have to call it on a separate Dygraph object. I've updated the example to show that approach. It only uses public APIs, though I'm not sure I prefer it to yours!

Comment: nice. I think that one is cleaner and feels less hacky :-) works perfectly btw

Comment: As of tonight, you can even get it in browser context: `Dygraph._require('dygraphs/src/dygraph-utils.js').numberValueFormatter` (very very positive side effect of splitting the tests from the code-under-test as the former needs precisely this from the latter). New release, targetting the upcoming Debian 12, coming soon.